# How Oracle creates the execution plan when the query has user-defined function?

Tags: oracle, query-optimization, oracle19c

If a query has user-defined functions, or system-generated functions etc in the query, are they calculated and written in the execution plan? If so, how is it calculated?

Comment: what do you mean by 'calculated'? The execution plan does not calculate functions, and may not even show them. PL/SQL functions, be they user-written or oracle-supplied, are called upon execution of the SQL.

Comment: For example, if I used a user-defined function in my select query, it will have a cost for the database.  Or it can be a database function like max, avg also. How can I see the the cost of that function for the database?

Comment: Oracle has no idea how much a user-created function will cost, as it depends on too many things, so it's cost is not included. As for the 'internal' functions, like min/max, their cost is computed by the steps taken to compute them: e.g. it is a hash group by or a sort group by, ....